# Django - ImportError at /graphql

Tags: python, django, django-models, graphql

Well, I tried to start GraphQL on Django's local server. But got a mistake that:

```
You need to pass a valid Django Model in UserType.Meta, received "auth.User".
```

Exception value is:

```
Exception Value:    
You need to pass a valid Django Model in UserType.Meta, received "auth.User".
```

To be honest, I don't really understand where I can find 'UserType.Meta. The model about users looks like (models.py):

```
# user - связь с пользователем один-к-одному
# website - юрл, по которому можно больше узнать о пользователе
# bio - о себе (Капитан Очевидность)
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)

    # __str__ - более удобное отобажение в админке
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

'schema.py' looks like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from Start import models
import graphene


# Всё заканчивается на type ибо они соответсвуют Graphql

class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class AuthorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile


class FileType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.File


class TagType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Tag
```

So, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you also include your GraphQL code?

Comment: @ettanany, yes, of course. Already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` returns the string `"auth.User"` instead of the model `User`. The following should fix your issue:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

 
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

You can also import `User` directly from `django.contrib.auth.models` but `get_user_model()` is preferred as it works also when you use a custom auth model in your settings file.